# Interpolate values between two cells

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I've got a spreadsheet that looks like this in Libre Office Calc:

```
    +-----------+
    |     |  A  |
    |  1  | 444 |
    |  2  |     |
    |  3  |     |
    |  4  |     |
    |  5  |     |
    |  n  |     |
    | n+1 | 938 |
    +-----------+
```

A(1) < A(n+1), 444 and 938 are used as a matter of example.

Is there a way to automatically fill the cells between A(1) and A(n+1) with integer values (by repeating them if needed) ?

Expected result:

```
    +-----------+   +-----------+
    |     |  A  |   |     |  A  |
    |  1  | 444 |   |  1  | 444 |
    |  2  |     |   |  2  | 527 |
    |  3  |     |   |  3  | 610 |
    |  4  |     |   |  4  | 693 |
    |  5  |     |   |  5  | 776 |
    |  6  |     |   |  6  | 859 |
    |  7  | 938 |   |  7  | 938 |
    +-----------+   +-----------+
```

Another example:

```
    +-----------+   +-----------+
    |     |  A  |   |     |  A  |
    |  1  |  5  |   |  1  |  5  |
    |  2  |     |   |  2  |  5  |
    |  3  |     |   |  3  |  6  |
    |  4  |     |   |  4  |  6  |
    |  5  |     |   |  5  |  7  |
    |  6  |     |   |  6  |  7  |
    |  7  |  8  |   |  7  |  8  |
    +-----------+   +-----------+
```

Thank you.

Comment: Copy `=[previous cell]+83` to all open cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an even distribution, with each cell rounded up to the next integer, enter the following formula into cell A2:

`=ROUNDUP(A$1+(ROW()-ROW(A$1))*(A$7-A$1)/(ROW(A$7)-ROW(A$1)))`

replacing *n* with the row of the last value (in your example 7). Then copy the cell down up to An (*not* An+1).

---

If you want the same values as in your example, take this formula:

`=ROUNDUP(A1+(A$n-A$1)/(ROW(A$n)-ROW(A$1)))`

But this suffers from a severe rounding bias: This adds a rounded up value of 83 from row to row, but for the last step there is only 79 remaining, making it significantly smaller. In the upper formula, the rounded difference changes between 82 and 83 from row to row, resulting in a more even spread.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this "manually":

- Add a collumn with values 1, ..., 7 (column A in my answer, the numbers 444 and 938 are in column B)
- Calculate the difference between two cells: `TEMPCELL = ROUNDUP((B7-B1)/(A7-A1);0)` (you seem to want the greater number, so I used `ROUNDUP`)
- in each of the empty cells in column B, enter `=(A2-1)*TEMPCELL+$B$1`

or (second idea, seems better to me)

- don't use the "helper column", just calculate the value of `TEMPCELL` (because A7-A1 in the example is just 6, there is no need for coulmn A in this step)
- in the cell below 444, enter `=B1+TEMPCELL` and drag the formula downwards

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to plot the series:

- select the series
- right click
- format data series
- Plot Options - select Continue line

[image]